# json array data not adding in the arraylist and getting null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Json array data not adding in the ArrayList and Returning null pointer exception

```
public void select_order_info(final String selectedItem,final  String month ) {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while loading...");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Class_Global.BASE_URL + "booking_details.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            //System.out.println("response="+response);
            parseJSON_select_order_info(response);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }) {


        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("selectedItem",selectedItem);
            params.put("month",month);



            return params;
        }

    };
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 10, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}


public void parseJSON_select_order_info(String response) {

    try {

        JSONArray array_booking_info = new JSONArray(response);

        for (int i = 0; i < array_booking_info.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject Object = array_booking_info.getJSONObject(i);
            Order order=new Order();
            order.setCheck_in(Object.getString("check_in"));
            order.setCheck_out(Object.getString("check_out"));
            order.setOrder_no(Object.getString("order_no"));
            //in_data= Object.getString("check_in");
            // out= Object.getString("check_out");
            //  order_no=Object.getString("order_no");

            arrayList_order_info.add(order);
           // System.out.print(array_booking_info.length());
           // Toast.makeText(getContext(), arrayList_order_info.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        arrayAdapter_calender=new ArrayAdapter_Calender(getContext(),R.layout.list_calender,arrayList,null,order_no,null,et_month,arrayList_order_info);
        gridview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter_calender);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


public class ArrayAdapter_Calender extends ArrayAdapter {
    Context context;
    ArrayList arrayList;
    ArrayList arrayList_booking;
    int day_check_in;
    int day_check_out;
    int days;
    String in;
    String out;
    String order_no;
    String first_name,last_name;
    String in_date,out_date,order_no_date;
    ArrayList<Order> arrayList_order_info;
    JSONArray array_booking,array_booking_info;
    EditText et_month;
    String selectedItem;
    String month,in_data;
    public ArrayAdapter_Calender(Context context, int resource, ArrayList arrayList, ArrayList arrayList_booking,  String order_no, JSONArray array_booking,   EditText et_month, ArrayList<Order> arrayList_order_info) {
        super(context, resource, arrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.arrayList_booking=arrayList_booking;

        this.day_check_in=day_check_in;
        this.day_check_out=day_check_out;
        this.days=days;
        this.in=in;
        this.out=out;
        this.order_no=order_no;
        this.first_name=first_name;
        this.last_name=last_name;
        this.array_booking=array_booking;
        this.in_date=in_date;
        this.out_date=out_date;
        this.order_no_date=order_no_date;
        this.arrayList_order_info=arrayList_order_info;
        this.et_month=et_month;
        this.in_data=in_data;
        this.array_booking_info=array_booking_info;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View viewGuest = convertView;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        viewGuest = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_calender, null);
        final TextView tv_date = (TextView) viewGuest.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);

        tv_date.setText(arrayList.get(position).toString());

        for(int i=1;i<=31;i++) {
            if (arrayList.get(position).equals(i)) {

                tv_date.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
        }
        try {

            //JSONArray array_booking = new JSONArray(response);

            for (int i = 0; i < array_booking.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject Object = array_booking.getJSONObject(i);


                in= Object.getString("check_in");
                out= Object.getString("check_out");
                order_no=Object.getString("order_no");
                //first_name=Object.getString("firstname");
                // last_name=Object.getString("lastname");

                String[] values_check_in = in.split("-");
                day_check_in = Integer.parseInt(values_check_in[2]);

                String[] values_check_out = out.split("-");
                day_check_out = Integer.parseInt(values_check_out[2]);
                //days=day_check_out-day_check_in;

                // arrayList_booking.add(day_check_in);
                //arrayList_booking.add(day_check_out);
                // days={day_check_in,day_check_out};

                // arrayList_booking.add(day_check_in);
                // arrayList_booking.add(day_check_out);
                for(int j=day_check_in;j<=day_check_out;j++) {
                    if (arrayList.get(position).equals(j)) {

                            tv_date.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

                    }


                }
                tv_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        selectedItem=arrayList.get(position).toString();
                        month=et_month.getText().toString();
                       // Toast.makeText(getContext(),selectedItem,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        select_order_info(selectedItem,month);
                        try {

                            // JSONArray array_booking = new JSONArray(response);

                            for (int j = 0; j < arrayList_order_info.size(); j++) {
                                //Toast.makeText(getContext(),arrayList_order_info.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //JSONObject Object = array_booking_info.getJSONObject(j);
                               // in=arrayList_order_info.get(j).getCheck_in();
                               // Toast.makeText(getContext(), in, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                in= arrayList_order_info.get(j).getCheck_in();
                               out= arrayList_order_info.get(j).getCheck_out();
                               order_no=arrayList_order_info.get(j).getCheck_out();

                                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
                                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dilogue_info);

                                dialog.setTitle("Hello");

                                TextView tv_check_in = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_check_in);
                                TextView tv_check_out = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_check_out);
                                TextView tv_order_no = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_no);




                                tv_check_in.setText(in);
                                tv_check_out.setText(out);
                                tv_order_no.setText(order_no);



                                dialog.show();

                            }
                        }

                        catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    }
                });

            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    /*              gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                   selectedItem=arrayList.get(i).toString();
                   month=et_month.getText().toString();
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(),selectedItem,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   select_order_info(selectedItem,month);

                   try {

                      // JSONArray array_booking = new JSONArray(response);

                       for (int j = 0; j < array_booking_info.length(); j++) {

                           JSONObject Object = array_booking_info.getJSONObject(j);


                           in= Object.getString("check_in");
                           out= Object.getString("check_out");
                           order_no=Object.getString("order_no");

                           final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
                           dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dilogue_info);

                           dialog.setTitle("Hello");

                           TextView tv_check_in = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_check_in);
                           TextView tv_check_out = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_check_out);
                           TextView tv_order_no = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_order_no);




                           tv_check_in.setText(in);
                           tv_check_out.setText(out);
                           tv_order_no.setText(order_no);



                           dialog.show();

                       }
                   }

                   catch (Exception e) {
                       Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

               }
           });
*/


        return viewGuest;
    }



}
```

Comment: share your json...

Comment: share error log

Answer (score 1):

From `parseJSON_select_order_info()` you have set the adapter

```
ArrayAdapter_Calender(getContext(),R.layout.list_calender,arrayList,null,order_no,null,et_month,arrayList_order_info);
            gridview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter_calender);
```

here you are passing 6th param as null that is `array_booking` in `ArrayAdapter_Calender` and you have used that array_booking in getView() so it will cause the NullPointerException

```
 for (int i = 0; i < array_booking.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject Object = array_booking.getJSONObject(i);
}
```